# how to split a word in mineflayer package node.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

hello I use mineflayer package and i want to split an in game message like
Guild > [RANK] IGN [Guild Rank] : message
I want to split the IGN so I can use it on other stuff

I tried a few split methods but not working iam not really that good with coding iam kind of new please help with this issue

Comment: Could you add some of your previous attempts to your question, that way we can help yuo debug it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question? Since it is quite vague, please add other information, like the code you tried, the approaches you have thought of. Also, I see that the [mineflayer](https://npmjs.com/package/mineflayer) is a package for making Minecraft bots, not for Discord Bots, so why'd you add the tag discord.js to it? I'm a bit curious.